# Separar una expresión lógica con expresiones regulares

Tags: java, regex

Buen día, estoy intentando separar la siguiente expresión lógica

**[(p->q)^p]->q**

Con la siguiente expresión regular

```
String[] espresionSeparada = expresion.split("(?=[pq^()->])");
```

Pero al ejecutarlo lo separa de la siguiente manera:

```
[, (, p, -, >, q, ), ^, p], -, >, q
```

No sé como decirle que -> esto es un solo símbolo, tampoco sé como decirle que separe la p del corchete(p])

Gracias por su apoyo

Answer (score 1):

Cuando hacemos `[]` matchea UNO de los caracteres que está adentro, por ello va a matchear "-" y por separado ">", para capturar "->" se puede hacer otro grupo `(?=->)`.

Los corchetes no los está matcheando en absoluto, el primer elemento está matchando en verdad "(" pero como el Positive Lookahead matchea pero no consume los caracteres, al hacer split deja al match en el grupo siguiente, el "[" queda afuera del match de "(" al hacer el split. El "p]" está siendo matcheado por "p", como luego matchea "-", y no matchea el "]" lo deja en grupo junto con la "p" (Porque usamos Positive Lookahead).

Para usar una única expresión regular, la misma debería incluír todos los caracteres, también los corchetes (`\[\]`) y por separado "->" unidos por un "OR" lógico `|` asi:

```
(?=[pq^()\[\]])|(?=->)
```

Dejo un prueba de concepto en JavaScript con una sintáxis muy similar a Java.

```js
const expresion = "[(p->q)^p]->q".split(/(?=[pq^()\[\]])|(?=->)/g)

console.log(expresion)
```

Otra alternativa es capturar todo lo que sea "->" OR todo los caracteres individuales que no sean "-" o ">", así:

```
(?=->)|(?=[^->])
```